# How to apply a CSS that is fetched from the application as a string in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I have a GWT application that at some time gets a string from the server that represents a CSS file content. Is it possible to apply this 'CSS' string using GWT to the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```java
Element head = Document.get().getElementsByTagName("head").getItem(0);
StyleElement style = Document.get().createStyleElement();
style.setType("text/css");
style.setInnerHTML("your css goes here");
head.appendChild(style);
```